# createSelector not memoize

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

Try understand how to work createSelector

I wrote a small example: [My example](https://codesandbox.io/s/createselector-xeoqk?file=/src/features/test/TestComponent.js:494-508)

Why is it that when I update the state unrelated (push button Change counter) to the createSelector arguments, a callback occurs(console output "calculation")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, because **you are calling `createSelector` *every time this component renders***.  That means that it's a *new* selector instance every time.

Memoization only works if you create a selector instance *once*, and then reuse that selector each time.

Move the `selectA/B/C` functions  and `const selectABC = createSelector()` to be *outside* of this component, and it should work.

I'd also suggest reading through the [Deriving Data with Selectors](https://redux.js.org/usage/deriving-data-selectors) page in the Redux docs.